# Dart - String replaceAll from json

Tags: dart

I have some Dart code that need replace all the keyword to full string based on a json list. I now using the most easy method to replaceAll string one by one but it seem not ok to work on a very long json, how do write a function take json and replace based on the key label field?

```
String replaceString(String str) {
    str = str.replaceAll('key_a', 'created');
    str = str.replaceAll('key_b', 'replied');
    str = str.replaceAll('key_c', 'assigned');
    str = str.replaceAll('key_d', 'unassigned');
    str = str.replaceAll('key_e', 'terminated');
    return str;
  }
```

json get from api

```
{
    "key_a": {
        "label": "created",
        "type": ""
    },
    "key_b": {
        "label": "replied",
        "type": ""
    },
    "key_c": {
        "label": "assigned",
        "type": ""
    }
..... and many more
}
```

Comment: You could make a `Map<String, String>` where the key is your key, and value is label. Then you can use `replaceAllMapped` from `String`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html where you are using a regular expression that splits your input into individual words and then check each word if it is in the `Map` and do a replacement if that is the case.

Comment: But I don't really understand what you input is and what kind of replacements you want. Do you want to replace also if `key` is part of a word?

Comment: @julemand101,  example original string is "this is key_a" , so after go through function the string become "this is created"